# zsh: completion menu. How to place common part of names?

Tags: zsh, tab-completion

I have completion menu configured in my zsh. It works great, no problem.

Now I want to make my zsh act like that:

Let's say there are 3 files in a directory:

1. somefile_first
2. somefile_second
3. somefile_third

Now when I press [TAB], I get completion menu with the first file placed in the command line.
But I want zsh to complete the common part of file names (in this example it would be **somefile_**), do **not** place anything else after the common part, and let me navigate through completion menu.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is old but I stumbled upon it when looking for the same answer. Here is what I found out.

AFAIK when using completion menu zsh will always place highlighted completion in the command line. However you can make it less hasty.

```
unsetopt menucomplete
setopt automenu
```

Changes the behaviour so

- first <kbd>TAB</kbd> completes the common part
- second lists completions without changing command line
- third starts the menu and completes command line with highlighted completion

If you prefer no command line changes than fancy menu unset automenu too:

```
unsetopt menucomplete automenu
```

That gives bash-like completion. Only common part is completed and propositions are listed.

Comment: For some reason nothing took effect.

Comment: Does adding `autoload -Uz compinit` and `compinit` before these lines change anything?